# $e^{\pi\sqrt N}$ is very close to an integer for some smallish $N$s. What about $\pi^{e\sqrt N}$?

Tags: approximation, irrational-numbers, pi

[Heegner numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) (1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 19, 43, 67, 163 - let's use symbol $H_n$) are know for peculiar property that $e^{\pi\sqrt{H_n}}$ are *almost* integers:

$$e^{\pi \sqrt{19}}  \approx 96^3+744-0.22$$
$$e^{\pi \sqrt{43}}  \approx 960^3+744-0.00022$$
$$e^{\pi \sqrt{67}}  \approx 5280^3+744-0.0000013$$
$$e^{\pi \sqrt{163}} \approx 640320^3+744-0.00000000000075$$

(given that they are all less than 200, it goes far beyond "chance" and "randomness")

Even stranger, related to the above:

$$19 = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3+1$$

$$43 = 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 3+1$$

$$67 = 11 \cdot 2 \cdot 3+1$$

$$163 = 27 \cdot 2 \cdot 3+1$$

and

$$96^3 =(2^5 \cdot 3)^3$$

$$960^3=(2^6 \cdot 3 \cdot 5)^3$$

$$5280^3=(2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11)^3$$

$$640320^3=(2^6 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 23 \cdot 29)^3$$

---

Related to this, I would like to know:

*Are there natural numbers N (of fairly similar range, so, lets say under 500) that produce "almost" integers in the expression $\pi^{e\sqrt{N}}$?*

If yes, do they have other interesting properties, like Heegner numbers do?

If not, all right, one more reason to appreciate Heegners. :)

Comment: I find that $744$ remarkable too.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: In a paper by Ken Ono, starting with $744$ and $24$ (the dimensions of the Leech lattice), he uses $744-24 =720$ to find trace formulas for certain modular forms. I'll look for that paper.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII That's very interesting, thank you.

Comment: See Ono's _Theorems 1 and 2_ in this paper ["p-adic properties of values of the modular j-function"](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/079.pdf)

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: To quote Ed Witten, *"...holomorphic CFT with central charge $c=24$, and the partition function of the CFT is precisely $j-744$..."* (Whatever that means.) See this section on [Monstrous Moonshine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine#Conjectured_relationship_with_quantum_gravity).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII As soon as I get done with my homework. Monstrously interesting, thanks again.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sci.math.research/PSQTfJqGCJM https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sci.math.research/PSQTfJqGCJMhttps://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sci.math.research/H-C7n4Yl9PI

Comment: Also notable is that $H=19, 43, 67, 163=4p-1$ for $p=5, 11, 17, 41$, and every $H$ and $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Up to 100000, the 10 best $N$ such that $e^{\pi\sqrt{N}}$ is almost an integer. The error $\delta$ is given such that the nearest integer is at $10^{\delta}$ from the result.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
N & \delta \\\hline
163 & -12.12\\
4\cdot163 & -9.79\\
9\cdot163 & -8.01\\
58 & -6.75\\
16\cdot163  & -6.51\\
67 & -5.87\\
22905 & -5.61\\
95041 & -5.55\\
54295 & -5.37\\
25\cdot163  & -5.2\\
\end{array}
$$

As you can see, no $N$ beats 163 up to 100000. (For [*N* = 4 x 163](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192255/on-e-pi-sqrt4-cdot163-and-unusual-connections).)

For $\pi^{e\sqrt{N}}$, the behaviour is much more regular and you obtain :

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
N & \delta \\\hline
66972 & -5.03 \\
85516 & -5.01 \\
53204 & -4.91 \\
46665 & -4.9 \\
50237 & -4.8 \\
93909 & -4.53 \\
52970 & -4.4 \\
10024 & -4.32 \\
84702 & -4.17 \\
6814 & -4.17 \\
\end{array}$$

So, it seems there is something strange in $e^{\pi\sqrt{N}}$ that makes that question interesting !

Comment: Thanks, thats great result, and thats maybe why there is no Heegner number greater than 163. Could you perhaps run the same calculation for PI^E instead E^PI? (I switched E and PI on purpose in the question, thats was the point of my question, but people started editing it and the clarity was lost..))

Comment: @VividD done ! and added an array with the results.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: @Xoff Indeed, there is something 'strange' afoot in the $e^{\pi\sqrt{N}}$ results; this comment is _far_ too small to do the topic justice, but searching on 'Heegner number' (as mentioned in the OP) will take you on a journey into the deep wilds of number theory...

Comment: @Xoff: I made a small tweak to your table to show the square multiples of $163$. I hope it's ok.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII it's ok !

Comment: Instead of the last sentence I'd remark that $\pi^x$ is extremely dull and unnatural compared to $e^x$.

Answer (score 10):

The phenomenon with the Heegner numbers can be generalized to,

$$e^{\pi\sqrt{-d}/a}\tag1$$

with *discriminants* $d=b^2-4ac$, of the quadratic,

$$P(n) = an^2+bn+c\tag2$$

These $d$ have very interesting properties.

**I. Connection to prime-generating polynomials:**

I'm sure you are familiar with Euler's,

$$P(n) =n^2+n+41\tag3$$

However, there are *other* optimum prime-generating polynomials with $a\neq1$,

$$P(n) =2n^2+29\tag4$$

$$P(n) =2n^2+2n+19\tag5$$

$$P(n) =3n^2+3n+23\tag6$$

$$P(n) =4n^2+163\tag7$$

$$P(n) =6n^2+6n+31\tag8$$

and others. Using the values of their $a,d$ into $(1)$, one gets,

$$\begin{aligned}
&e^{\pi\sqrt{163}/1} = 640320^3 +743.999999\dots\\
&e^{\pi\sqrt{232}/2} = e^{\pi\sqrt{58}} = 396^4 -104.0000001\dots\\ 
&e^{\pi\sqrt{148}/2} = e^{\pi\sqrt{37}} = (84\sqrt{2})^4 +103.99997\dots\\
&e^{\pi\sqrt{267}/3} = 300^3 + 41.99997\dots\\
&e^{\pi\sqrt{10432}/4} = e^{\pi\sqrt{4\cdot163}} = (640320^3+744)^2 - 2\cdot \color{blue}{196883}.99999\dots\\
&e^{\pi\sqrt{708}/6} = 1060^2 + 9.99992\dots
\end{aligned}$$

and so on.

1. What's [196884](https://oeis.org/search?q=196884&language=english&go=Search)? (OEIS)
2. And here why $\log(196883) < 4\pi,\,$ or approx $12.19 < 12.56,$ is important to [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine#Conjectured_relationship_with_quantum_gravity). (Huh?)

More on these prime-generating polynomials [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0023).

**II. Connection to pi formulas:**

In addition, each one of these integer approximations can be used in a [Ramanujan-Sato pi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series). The most famous of course, is with $d = 4\cdot58$,

$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{2 \sqrt 2}{99^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(4k)!}{k!^4} \frac{58\cdot455k+1103}{396^{4k}}$$

**III. Connection to Pell equations:**

Furthermore, they are also connected to *Pell equations*. For example, the fundamental solution to,

$$x^2-3\cdot163y^2 = 1$$

$$x,\;y = 7592629975,\;343350596$$

hence the [fundamental unit](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html),

$$U =x+y\sqrt{489} =7592629975+343350596\sqrt{489} = \big(35573\sqrt{3}+4826\sqrt{163}\big)^2$$

Then,

$$\Big(3\sqrt{3}\big(U^{1/2}-U^{-1/2}\big)+6\Big)^3 = 640320^3$$

You can read more in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189126/why-do-pell-equations-appear-in-ramanujans-pi-formulas). There is a lot more to $e^{\pi\sqrt{n}}$ than being near-integers, it seems.

Comment: Mind-boggling !

Comment: $\exp(4\pi)\approx 286751$. Nowhere even close to 196884.

Comment: I don't follow your example (7). $d=-4\cdot4\cdot163$ which gives $\exp(\pi\sqrt{163})$ again. But your radicand is $10432=64\cdot163$.